# Fitbit Authentication using UIWebview iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview, google-oauth, fitbit

I'm trying to connect to Fitbit on my iOS native app. I'm using a uiwebview to display to login and authorization screen. If the user login using his/her Fitbit credentials it works fine, but if they try to login using Google or Facebook I'm having trouble. When using Google, there is a popup to login and once the user is authenticated, it tries to do a callback to the parent window but since I'm using a uiwebview it just shows a blank page. Same with Facebook. Anyone have dealt with this before? It works on Safari but I need to do it in-app to get the access code and all the data to link the account and send to the server. Any help?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Go carefully through https://appengineer.in/2016/04/30/fitbit-aouth-in-ios-app/ . You will get step by step solution and source code for FitBit integration